# Send print command to printer that is not default printer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I tried to send a `Printdocument` in C# to a printer that was not set as the default printer in Windows. How can it be possible?

There are two printers on the system, and I send a print command to a thermal printer that is not set as the default printer.

When I use

```
MyPrintdocument.Print();
```

it sends the print command to the default printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check MSDN. Assuming you are using the `PrintDocument` class, it says you can set the printer settings via [PrintDocument.PrinterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings.aspx). And then you can probably set the printer via [PrinterSettings.PrinterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername.aspx).